# Ssh, run a command on login, and then Stay Logged In?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface, automation

I tried this with expect, but it didn't work: it closed the connection at the end.

Can we run a script via ssh which will log into remote machines, run a command, and not disconnect?

So ssh in a machine, cd to such and such a directory, and then run a command, and stay logged in.

-Jonathan

(expect I used)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password [lrange $argv 0 0]
spawn ssh root@marlboro "cd /tmp; ls -altr | tail"
expect "?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"
interact
```

Comment: Is it just me or are you "automating" password authentication this way, instead of using pubkeys or other sane method?

Answer (score 33):

Add a `; /bin/bash` to the end of your command line on the remote side?   That is:

```
spawn ssh -t root@marlboro "cd /tmp; ls -altr | tail; /bin/bash -i"
```

Even better, change root's .bashrc to be something like this:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="cd /tmp && ls -altr | tail ; unset PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

:)

Comment: You may want to add `-i` to that bash.

Comment: Yeh, I suppose :)

Comment: When I do that, tab completion breaks in the new shell (even with "-i") -- any idea why / how to fix?

Comment: Tab completion really needs a full pty to work.  Doing that command list is probably breaking it somehow.  Hacky update to my answer coming, check shortly :)

Comment: I tested my new answer here, it works great.  A little rough, but it works.

Comment: Try `ssh -t` to allocate a pty.

Comment: +1 using -t to ssh was vital for me

Comment: whats that spawn up there ?

Comment: It's the expect command to run an external program.

Comment: This also works for `vagrant ssh`. It enables you to ssh to vagrant, run commands and stay logged in not exiting, ex. `vagrant ssh -- -t "whatever_commands; /bin/bash -i"`.

Answer (score 8):

The probably easiest and cleanest way to ssh into a server, spawn an interactive shell and run commands inside that shell is to create a custom rc file for bash.

In your custom bashrc file on the server, first source the default file and then add your custom commands, e.g.

~/.bashrc_custom:

```
. ~/.bashrc
cd dir/
workon virtualenvproject
```

You can then start your SSH session like this:

```
$ ssh -t server "/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc_custom -i"
```

The `-t` option forces a pseudo-tty allocation, so that things like tab-completion work.

The `--rcfile` option specifies which rcfile to load instead of the default one. Important: you must put "double-dash arguments" on the command line before the single-character options in order to be recognized.

The `-i` argument to /bin/bash is there to invoke an interactive shell.

Comment: actually not. What to do if I want to run different commands for each connection?

Answer (score 5):

If you are ok with doing this in Python, [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) has an example that does almost exactly what you are asking for:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect ('Name .*: ')
child.sendline ('anonymous')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline ('noah@example.com')
child.expect ('ftp> ')
child.sendline ('ls /pub/OpenBSD/')
child.expect ('ftp> ')
print child.before   # Print the result of the ls command.
child.interact()     # Give control of the child to the user.
```

To do this with ssh instead of ftp, you'd want code similar to the following (the example files in pexpect have much more details and info, but here are the basics):

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('ssh root@marlboro')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline ('password')
child.expect ('prompt# ')
child.sendline ('cd /tmp')
child.expect ('prompt# ')
child.sendline ('ls -altr | tail')
child.expect ('prompt# ')
print child.before, child.after   # Print the result of the ls command.
child.interact()     # Give control of the child to the user.
```

Don't get me wrong, I LOVE expect (especially autoexpect), but python is just soooo much easier for me to grok.

Comment: I too am transitioning from expect to pexpect. python is now much more ubiquitous.

Answer (score 3):

If anybody wants information on what is happening in the background, you should take a look at the sshd manual:

> When a user successfully logs in, sshd does the following:
>
> 1. If the login is on a tty, and no command has been specified, prints last login time and /etc/motd (unless prevented in the configuration file or by ~/.hushlogin; see the FILES section).
> 2. If the login is on a tty, records login    time.
> 3. Checks /etc/nologin and    /var/run/nologin; if one exists, it prints the contents and quits (unless root).
> 4. Changes    to run with normal user privileges.
> 5. Sets up    basic environment.
> 6. Reads the file ~/.ssh/environment, if it exists, and users are allowed to change their environment.  See the PermitUserEnvironment option in sshd_config(5).
> 7. Changes    to user's home directory.
> 8. If ~/.ssh/rc exists, runs it; else if /etc/ssh/sshrc exists,       runs it; otherwise runs xauth(1).  The ``rc'' files are given the X11   authentication protocol and cookie in standard input. See SSHRC, below.
> 9. Runs user's shell **or** command.

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd(8)#LOGIN_PROCESS

Answer (score 1):

If you like `tmux`:

```sh
ssh -t user@host "cd /tmp; tmux a || tmux"
```

After logging in, this always runs `cd /tmp` on the remote host. Then it tries to attach to an already running `tmux` session where you can continue to work where you left off after the last `ssh` disconnection (simulate this by typing sequentially <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>) or `tmux` detachment (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>), and if there is no running `tmux` session, then it will start a new `tmux` session, which will also keep you logged in using the shell configured for that user.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally avoid using ssh in this kind of way as it defeats it's purpose.
Do an

```
ssh-add -l | grep "file_of_your_rsa_priv_key_here"
```

to see if your key is listed in the ssh active session pool or else add it yourself (with ssh-add).

Answer (score 0):

Solutions here partially worked for me, but not for an ongoing process. Adding `; bash` was the key to return to bash after (thanks to [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/934533/66800)).

```bash
# Starts SSH, runs the script, and stays logged in after exiting script.
ssh foo@bar.com -t "./runUntilCtrlC.sh; bash"

# Troubleshooting:
# Check the remote shell is bash with `echo "$SHELL"`.
```

```bash
# For a bonus, make it an alias if you do it all the time
#
# Add to bottom of your local profile (~/.zprofile or ~/.bash_profile)
alias runFoo='ssh foo@bar.com -t "./run.sh; bash"'

# save and quit editing

# Load it immediately, instead of waiting for reboot.
source ~/.zprofile # or ~/.bash_profile or whatever

# Then use the alias
runFoo
```