# Can I execute some commands when starting ssh session before getting to interactive mode?

Tags: ssh

When starting ssh session with ssh command I seem to have two options - default interactive session with default env and starting from home directory - or to execute arbitrary command but non-interactively (even tricks like `ssh "command; command; bash -i -l"` don't seem to do much good). Quite often I want interactive session, but with something happening before that - normally a directory change, or sometimes system environment adjustment. These things would vary from session to session, so I cannot just stick them into `.bashrc` or so.

Is there any way to make that happen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm self-answering, as I've finally discovered the secret. Neither `-t` option for `ssh`, nor `-l` option for `bash` will lead to login shell on their own - but in combination they work.

`ssh user@host.com -t 'cd /some/where; FOO=BAR NUMBER=42 bash -l'` changes directory, sets environment variables, and then starts proper login shell (the only difference I've found so far is that `/etc/motd` isn't displayed this way - it's normally  `ssh`'s or `login`'s responsibility, not `bash`'s - other than that everything seems to work perfectly, and all environmental variables are identical).

These environment / directory changes happen after ssh, so they're not restricted by `PermitUserEnvironment` and related settings (exactly as planned), but before `.bashrc`/`.profile` get executed. This has upsides and downsides - it is harder to just override something that gets set from bash init scripts like `PS1`, but easier to pack exactly the right values into `ssh` command lines, and have `.profile` do all the heavy lifting.

And if really necessary, it's actually pretty easy to get bash to execute something after `.profile` with command line like `ssh user@foo.com -t 'cd /mnt; echo ". ~/.bash_profile; PS1=\"\\h-\w \"" >~/xxx; bash --init-file ~/xxx'` - very ugly when put that way, but these alternative `.profile` files can be prepared before.
(as far as I can tell `bash` has a few candidate locations for `.profile` script and will execute the first one found - `. file` doesn't have such automatic fallbacks, so you'll need to check where's your normal `profile` if you want to do that)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! I was looking to find a way to su into a user's account right after ssh'ing in, and the "-t" option made it work. Without that option, your shell doesn't have a prompt, doesn't have command history, dies from a SIGINT, etc.

Comment: This answer is really helpful but you're missing a few `;`s from the first ssh login string. It won't let me edit your answer because I'm not changing enough. I got this to work `ssh user@host.com -t 'cd /some/where; FOO=BAR; NUMBER=42; bash -l'`. I think that's what you intended.

Comment: @RobKwasowski No @taw's version is correct: Without the semicolons the variables are passed as environment variables to `bash -l` and thus set in the ensuing login shell, while in your version `$FOO` and `$NUMBER` are set locally in the "intermediate session" but lost once the login shell starts. Yours should work if you exported the variables (e.g., `export FOO=BAR;`), though you would gain nothing but verbosity over the other approach.

Answer (score 2):

Edit .bashrc and enclose your SSH-specific environment settings in:

```
if [ $SSH_TTY ]; then
    ...
fi
```

This would allow you to add settings specifically for SSH sessions. 'Course, if all you want is to set arbitrary environment variables right at the outset that vary by session, I don't know how you can make the machine guess them for you apart from typing them... no matter what, you'll need some testable condition to base the choice of settings on.

Answer (score 2):

From the `ssh` man page:

> Additionally, ssh reads ~/.ssh/environment, and adds lines of the format
>        “VARNAME=value” to the environment if the file exists and users are
>        allowed to change their environment.  For more information, see the
>        PermitUserEnvironment option in sshd_config(5).

which says:

> PermitUserEnvironment
>                Specifies whether ~/.ssh/environment and environment= options in
>                ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are processed by sshd(8).  The default is
>                “no”.  Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass
>                access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such
>                as LD_PRELOAD.

This facility could be used to conditionally execute statements in your remote `~/.bashrc` using the `if` structure that [**Mickey**](https://serverfault.com/questions/158054/can-i-execute-some-commands-when-starting-ssh-session-before-getting-to-interacti/158062#158062) suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run in this way : `ssh -t yourdomain 'cd /yourpath; bash'`

- `-t` : so that prompt sh'd appear
- `; bash` : so that it sh'd return back the control despite of executing command (here `cd`) and exiting from ssh session

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Please provide and explaination and/or documentation for commands or scripts to explain what they are for.

Comment: Thanks @CoryKnutson, I have made the changes as you requested